# Need to set TextTemplatingFileGenerator as Custom Tool on *.tt files or Visual Studio 2019 won't build your Entity Framework models

Tags: entity-framework, t4, visual-studio-2019

I just discovered that Visual Studio 2019 wouldn't rebuild my Entity Framework models. Even if I right clicked the EDMX diagram file and selected, "Run Custom Tool" nothing would happen. Lot of posts here and elsewhere said to also Run Custom Tool on each `*.tt` file. But that wasn't possible since the "Custom Tool" property of all `*.tt` files was not set. At first I figured I'd use the same custom tool indicated on my `.edmx` file, which is `EntityModelCodeGenerator`.

Solution: The `*.tt` files need to have `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` set as their Custom Tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Custom Tool property of each of your `*.tt` files to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`.

Comment: Custom tool for edmx: EntityModelCodeGenerator ? not found